# How to setup Cocos2d-x image resources properly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I can't seem to get my retina / non retina images to display properly.
With cocos2d changing the syntax often, I'm not sure what to use anymore.

I have tried tutorials [like this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48180/cocos2d-x-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1), but nothing seems to work.

My current resources are set up to `sd` & `hd` folders in the Resources directory (both versions of images have the same name, i've tried adding suffixes), I would like to pull the appropriate image for nonretina/retina iPad in cocos2d-x.

What is the current cocos2dx syntax to set directories? Do i have to set a specific suffix along with setting a directory? Please help.
Cocos2d-x v2.2

EDIT**
I'm testing on retina & nonretina ipad. If I include only non retina images its perfect on non retina iPad, and everything is tiny on retina as expected. Now when i add retina images to the project, the devices get confused and load random sizes, etc one image is retina, next one is non retina. This is because both versions have the same filename, but i have them in different directories `Resouces/sd` & `Resources/hd`. How do i set the cocos2dx v2.2.2 project to load from the appropriate directory? I've tried many tutorials and the cocos2dx example, they're not working for me.

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you have? Give an example of your setup (filenames), device you're testing on, what you expect to see and what really happens. PS: the suffixes for cocos2d-iphone are: -hd, -widehd, -ipad, -ipadhd. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053485/what-exactly-is-the-available-file-suffixes-for-cocos2d-used-for-multi-resoluti and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869085/cocos2d-2-1-and-wide-suffix and most of all: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Mechanism_of_loading_resources They're also in the source code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D See edit for further explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after many, many frustrating hours of trial and error, I've figured it out!
What i was doing wrong was importing `hd` & `sd` folders as Groups instead of Folder references..
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12932540/1992125) for details

Then I simply did this, and works perfectly non/retina & retina iPad:

```
AppDelegate.ccp

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);

    vector<string> searchPath;
    CCSize frameSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();

   if (frameSize.height > 1024)
       searchPath.push_back("hd");
   else
       searchPath.push_back("sd");
   CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPath);

   ...
}
```

Hope this saves somebody the trouble!